# WSO2 Multi-tenant from email not working. How to configure identiy server tenant wise from mail?

Tags: email, wso2, multi-tenant, identity

we used WSO2 Identity server 5.11.x for a Saas Project and we facing issues in sending email from tenant. emails are sending from only one email which is configured in the default tenant. in our case each tenant is separate customer they need to send emails from their email ID.

we tried the steps given in the wso2 docs but it not worked for me
link :https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/6.0.0/deploy/configure-email-sending/#configure-the-email-sender-per-tenant